# Linkedlist Inside Linkedlist in C

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I need to add a linked on each node. its posible?

In other words, each student has subjects and each one of them has a grade.

This is my Student structure working, but I can't implement a linkedlist inside.

[image: Example]

**

```
And ex output:
Estudent 1: 
Math
Filosophy
```

**

this is the implementation of the linkedlist.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "estudiante.h"

NodeStudent * create_student_node(int id, int edad){
    NodeStudent * newNode = malloc(sizeof(NodeStudent));
    if (!newNode) {
        return NULL;
    }
    newNode->id = id;
    newNode->next_student = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

StudentList * create_student_list(){
    StudentList * list = malloc(sizeof(StudentList));
    if (!list) {
        return NULL;
    }
    list->head = NULL;
    return list;
}

void add_student(int data, int edad, StudentList * list){
    NodeStudent * current = NULL;
    if(list->head == NULL){
        NodeStudent *nodoaux = create_student_node(data, edad);
        list->head = nodoaux;
    }
    else {
        current = list->head;
        while (current->next_student != NULL){
            current = current->next_student;
        }
        current->next_student = create_student_node(data, edad);
    }
}

void print_list(StudentList * list) {
    NodeStudent * actual = list->head;
    if(list->head == NULL) return;
    for(; actual != NULL; actual = actual->next_student) {
        printf("ID : %d \n", actual->id);
    }
}
```

header file

```
     typedef struct node_student {
    int id;
    struct subjects * next_subjects;
    struct node_student * next_student;
}NodeStudent;

typedef struct list_student {
    NodeStudent * head;
}StudentList;


StudentList * create_student_list();
void add_student(int data, int edad, StudentList * list);
void print_list(StudentList * list);
```

Comment: Whatever problem you're having is in the definition of `struct subjects`, since that's the thing you want a linked list of. Why would it be any harder to have a linked list of subjects than of students? The principles are identical.

Comment: I need each student to have a linked list of subjects and then add subjects to each of these

Comment: So....do that.  Have a `struct subject` pointer as a member of `struct student`, and have another one in `struct subject`.  It's typically called `next`.

Comment: And where do I keep the head of each student's subject list?
I need it for other functions like ordering.
How do I create a subject list within a node?
How do I add subjects to a node?

Comment: You write code to do it. At the very least you _try_ writing code to do it and show us where you got stuck. You've already written one singly-linked list, you're just doing the same thing again with different names.

Comment: To do a list inside-of-a-list, you simply have a pointer to the second list  as a member of your list node.

Comment: There already is one: `struct subjects * next_subjects;`. There's no reason that can't be the head of a per-student subject list. Whatever problem OP is having exists in the one struct they haven't shown, or in their head.

Comment: A linked-list sounds like a bad idea from the start. Sounds like you need a weak entity to store the course and student as a foreign key inside an array.